# display accented characters on mintty (cygwin) console?

Tags: cygwin, non-ascii-characters, iso-8859-1, mintty

in a nutshell, i would like to be able to type and display characters from iso-8859-1 on my cygwin mintty. unfortunately i haven't figured out how to do this.

my locale :

```
$ locale
LANG=C.ISO-8859-1
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

mintty is configured as an `xterm` (although it seems to make no difference what terminal emulation i choose), and through *options => text*, i have configured the 'locale' section as `C` and the character set as `ISO-8859-1`.

when i type any accented character from my keyboard, the character does not display on the terminal. however, if i invoke `cat`, the characters i type display correctly. also, when i edit using `vi` (well, `vim`, actually), i am able to type (and display) accented characters without problems. so the problem seems to have something to do with the shell and not with the terminal emulation itself.

furthermore, if i write a little script to make a file named, for example, `être.utx`, the file displays as `???tre.utx` when i `ls` it. looking at its hex, i get

```
$ ls *.utx | od -c -tx1
0000000 357 203 252   t   r   e   .   u   t   x  \n
         ef  83  aa  74  72  65  2e  75  74  78  0a
0000013
```

so it seems the script i wrote is creating a file whose name begins with the trigramme 0xEF 0x83 0xAA, rather than the single-byte character whose encoding should be 0xEA. i don't know how to interpret this ; i know it isn't utf-8, which would be 0xC3 0xAA.

it appears there is only one character set in my cygwin configuration that is configured to support 8859-1 : norwegian. [of course, i suppose i could learn norwegian, but i would prefer something a bit less strenuous, if possible...]

in any case, does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong ?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just set *mintty*'s locale to something utf8-ish.

In my case:

```
Window Menu (Alt+Space)
  Options… (o)
    Text (l.h. panel)
      Locale → en_GB
      Character Set → UTF-8

[Save]
```

Quit and restart

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ echo $'\u2154'
⅔
```

Nice

Comment: unfortunately utf-8 is a multi-byte character set. i'm constrained to working with iso-8859-1 for this project.